# Passing data from first to second modal view controller using storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard, segue

I'm developing a new iOS app
I have a view controller in my storyboard that has a text field. Using UITextFieldDelegate, upon pressing search on the keyboard I perform the segue to a table view controller.
But this second table view controller is embedded in a navigation view controller. The first view controller is not a part of it.
Segue is done using:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchTableViewController"];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFlipHorizontal];

    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

What I want to do is, pass data from the first view controller's text field to the other view controller in a NSString. How do I do this?

There's an IBOutlet, searchField on the text field in the first.
And in the second's header file a property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *searchText.
```

So how do I go about passing searchField.text to searchText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate your view controller you should cast it as your custom view controller subclass.  If you do this you can then set the `searchText` property value.

```
SearchTableViewController *vc = (SearchTableViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchTableViewController"];

vc.searchText = self.searchField.text;
```

Comment: Nope didn't work!
Caused app to crash

[UINavigationController setSearchText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a5e130
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setSearchText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a5e130'.

I casted it as you said and then simply
vc.searchText = self.searchField.Text;

and even

vc.searchText = @"Some Text";

Comment: Oh I get it, why the app crashed!
SearchTableViewController is the identifier for the navigation controller. The identifier for the view attached to the navigation controller is "SecondView"
Sorry, my bad!
Fixed it. Used topViewController and cast it to my custom class.
Instantiated SearchTableViewController with UINavigationController.

Comment: Thanks anyways! Your answer sure did help :D

Answer (score 0):

Another method is:

```
 UINavigationController *nav  = [segue destinationViewController];
 [((YourViewController *) [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]) setObject: object];
```